# Nav items not staying right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a nav bar that's got 3 segments (left nav, logo, right nav) however I can't get the right nav to float on the right regardless of what flex classes I'm using.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="header-navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar navbar-horizontal floating-nav navbar-dark navbar-without-dd-arrow navbar-shadow menu-border" role="navigation" data-menu="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <div class="brand-logo"></div>
                    <h2 class="brand-text mb-0">MyWebsite</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-toggle"><a class="nav-link modern-nav-toggle pr-0" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="feather icon-x d-block d-xl-none font-medium-4 primary toggle-icon"></i><i class="toggle-icon feather icon-disc font-medium-4 d-none d-xl-block collapse-toggle-icon primary" data-ticon="icon-disc"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-container main-menu-content navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2" data-menu="menu-container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/play"><i class="feather icon-home"></i><span>Play</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/stats"><i class="feather icon-bar-chart"></i><span>Statistics</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/leaderboard"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/">
            <div class="brand-logo"></div>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/register"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><span>Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from below, the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue is you are using `mr-auto` in last column rather then `ml-auto`
>   because you need margin left not right so that it align it-self to
>   right

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item mr-auto">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <div class="brand-logo"></div>
                    <h2 class="brand-text mb-0">MyWebsite</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-toggle"><a class="nav-link modern-nav-toggle pr-0" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="feather icon-x d-block d-xl-none font-medium-4 primary toggle-icon"></i><i class="toggle-icon feather icon-disc font-medium-4 d-none d-xl-block collapse-toggle-icon primary" data-ticon="icon-disc"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/play"><i class="feather icon-home"></i><span>Play</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/stats"><i class="feather icon-bar-chart"></i><span>Statistics</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/leaderboard"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i><span>Leaderboards</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Navbar 2</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/register"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><span>Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i><span>Login</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)